# how to insert data to a closest td with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get value of an `input textbox` and insert the value into a td in the same row.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<table class="test">  
  <tr ><td class="x"><input type="text" class="testinp"></td><td class="y">Fish</td><td class="z">Chicken</td></tr>
  <tr ><td class="x"><input type="text" class="testinp"></td><td class="y">Cricket</td><td class="z">Tenis</td></tr>
  <tr ><td class="x"><input type="text" class="testinp"></td><td class="y">Watch</td><td class="z">Hat</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('.testinp').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    var val =  $(this).val();
    $(this).find('td').closest('.z').html(val);            
  }
});
```

Now I am getting the value but cannot insert it into the td.

Comment: AngularJS would be a great solution to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) looks for the `selector` in the descendants of `input`, not the parents. So you need to use `$(this).closest('td')`.

Then, you can use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) like this:

```
$(this).closest('td').siblings('td.z').text(val);
```

or

get the nearest `tr`, and look for a `td` with `z` class:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td.z').text(val);
```

Comment: Might also be worthwhile to use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: And `.siblings()` instead of `.next()` :) I don't think `.next()` would match in this case. The documentation says: _Get the **immediately following sibling** of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it **retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector**._

Comment: @Boaz Your suggestion is working. Will you give this suggestion in answer?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `siblings()` for find class "z"

```js
$('.testinp').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        var val =  $(this).val();
        $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.z').text(val);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="test">  
      <tr ><td class="x"><input type="text" class="testinp"></td><td class="y">Fish</td><td class="z">Chicken</td></tr>
      <tr ><td class="x"><input type="text" class="testinp"></td><td class="y">Cricket</td><td class="z">Tenis</td></tr>
      <tr ><td class="x"><input type="text" class="testinp"></td><td class="y">Watch</td><td class="z">Hat</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with one more solution

```js
$('.testinp').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
      var val =  $(this).val();
      $(this).closest('tr').find('td.z').text(val);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="test">  
      <tr ><td class="x"><input type="text" class="testinp"></td><td class="y">Fish</td><td class="z">Chicken</td></tr>
      <tr ><td class="x"><input type="text" class="testinp"></td><td class="y">Cricket</td><td class="z">Tenis</td></tr>
      <tr ><td class="x"><input type="text" class="testinp"></td><td class="y">Watch</td><td class="z">Hat</td></tr>
</table>
```

Traverse till `tr` using `closest` and the find `td with class z`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(this).closest('td').next('td').html(val);
```

.find doesn't go up in the DOM, it goes down. So you won't find any td that are under your input field.

Edit: Sorry, forgot to remove the . point. I copied and edited your approach, it should say .next("td") of course.

Comment: This is his markup:  <td class="x">  So yes, there is a td? Or am I missing something? . Edit: Thank you, I got it now. I forgot to remove the "." from the selection above and totally missed it. Sorry :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('.testinp').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        var val =  $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('td').closest('.z').html(val);

    }
});
```

Comment: Note that `closest` finds the nearest _parent_ and not _sibling_.