# jquery - How to insert data into closest td after enter data in another column in same row (Dynamically create table row with button click)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to display the name after the id been enter in each dynamically created table row but the name did not display into the td. Data is confirmed get from database.

I have try from the side here but it didnt work for me
[how to insert data to a closest td with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559976/how-to-insert-data-to-a-closest-td-with-jquery)

this is the way i add table row with button click

```
    var count = 1;
 $('#btnadditem').click(function(){
    count = count + 1;

       var html_code = "<tr id='row"+count+"'>";
       html_code += "<td class='iID'><input type='text' id='itemID' style='width:100px'/></td>";
       html_code += "<td class='iName' colspan='3' style='width:150px'></td>";
       html_code += "<td class='Iqty'><input type='number' id='itemqty' style='width:70px'/></td>";
       html_code += "<td class='iPrc' style='width:80px'></td>";
       html_code += "<td><button type='button' name='remove' data-row='row"+count+"' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs remove' style='width:40px'>-</button></td>";   
       html_code += "</tr>";
       $('#maint').append(html_code);
 })//close function
```

This is the function to get the name when id detect any change

```
$('#maint').on('keyup','.iID',function(){
    var iic = $('#itemID').val();
    var action = "keyup2";
    $.ajax({method:"POST",
            url:"function/Function_AMain.php",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{"iic":iic,"ActionTaken":action},success: function(data){
                if(data.c == 1)
                {
                    alert(data.a);
                $(this).closest('tr').siblings('td.iName').text(data.a);
                }
            }})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say you're getting back a response from the server (Ajax), then I suspect that the problem lies with `$(this)` as its scope changes inside the `success` function.

Also, you gotta use the `find` function instead of `siblings` since `td`s are children of `tr` and not siblings.

Another thing is that should use var `var iic = $(this).find('input').val()` instead of `var iic = $('#itemID').val();` as `#itemID` will be repeated multiple times each time you click the add button. It's better off to remove that attribute completely from the input.

And finally, use the `html()` function instead of `text()` to set the value of an input element.

You can try the following:

```
var iic = $(this).find('input').val();
.
.
.
var thisObject = $(this); // cache the current this object
$.ajax({
       method:"POST",
       url:"function/Function_AMain.php",
       dataType:"json",
       data:{"iic":iic,"ActionTaken":action},
       success: function(data)
       {
           if(data.c == 1)
           {
               alert(data.a);
               // now use it here
               thisObject.closest('tr').find('td.iName').html(data.a);
           }
       }
});
```

Comment: My bad. Use the `find` method instead of `siblings` since `td` is children of `tr` and not sibling

Comment: nice, that solve the problem i met and i meet second problem is the second row that i type in different id but still display the name belong to first id...any idea about that?

Comment: if i change the var iic to $(this).val(); , it cant get any id from that

Comment: btw, i am still using text() instead of html() because html() doesn't work for me...